# SQL Nested Select statements with COUNT()

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'll try to describe as best I can, but it's hard for me to wrap my whole head around this problem let alone describe it....

I am trying to select multiple results in one query to display the current status of a database. I have the first column as one type of record, and the second column as a sub-category of the first column. The subcategory is then linked to more records underneath that, distinguished by status, forming several more columns.  I need to display every main-category/subcategory combination, and then the count of how many of each sub-status there are beneath that subcategory in the subsequent columns.  I've got it so that I can display the unique combinations, but I'm not sure how to nest the select statements so that I can select the count of a completely different table from the main query.  My problem lies in that to display the main category and sub category, I can pull from one table, but I need to count from a different table.  Any ideas on the matter would be greatly appreciated

Here's what I have.  The count statements would be replaced with the count of each status:

```
  SELECT wave_num "WAVE NUMBER",
     int_tasktype "INT / TaskType",
     COUNT (1) total,
     COUNT (1) "LOCKED/DISABLED",
     COUNT (1) released,
     COUNT (1) "PARTIALLY ASSEMBLED",
     COUNT (1) assembled
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
             (t.invn_need_type || ' / ' || s.code_desc) int_tasktype,
             t.task_genrtn_ref_nbr wave_num
        FROM sys_code s, task_hdr t
       WHERE     t.task_genrtn_ref_nbr IN
                    (SELECT ship_wave_nbr
                       FROM ship_wave_parm
                      WHERE TRUNC (create_date_time) LIKE SYSDATE - 7)
             AND s.code_type = '590'
             AND s.rec_type = 'S'
             AND s.code_id = t.task_type),
     ship_wave_parm swp
GROUP BY wave_num, int_tasktype
ORDER BY wave_num
```

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUzud.png

Comment: could you present more or less what you expect as result?

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Right now you have a cross join. Is that what you wanted? You should never use implicit joins anyway as they make it easy to get unintentional cross joins and other badness. IMplicit joins are a  SQl antipattern and there really is no excuse to still be using them.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing a bit,both regarding your problem and Oracle (which I've - unfortunately - never used), hopefully it will give you some ideas. Sorry for completely messing up the way you write SQL, SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)) simply confuses me, so I have to restructure:

```
with tmp(int_tasktype, wave_num) as
(select distinct (t.invn_need_type || ' / ' || s.code_desc), t.task_genrtn_ref_nbr  
 from sys_code s 
 join task_hdr t 
   on s.code_id = t.task_type
 where s.code_type = '590' 
   and s.rec_type = 'S'  
   and exists(select 1 from ship_wave_parm p
              where t.task_genrtn_ref_nbr = p.ship_wave_nbr
                and trunc(p.create_date_time) = sysdate - 7))

select t.wave_num "WAVE NUMBER", t.int_tasktype "INT / TaskType",
       count(*) TOTAL,
       sum(case when sst.sub_status = 'LOCKED'    then 1 end) "LOCKED/DISABLED",
       sum(case when sst.sub_status = 'RELEASED'  then 1 end) RELEASED, 
       sum(case when sst.sub_status = 'PARTIAL'   then 1 end) "PARTIALLY ASSEMBLED",
       sum(case when sst.sub_status = 'ASSEMBLED' then 1 end) ASSEMBLED
from tmp t
join sub_status_table sst
  on t.wave_num = sst.wave_num
group by t.wave_num, t.int_tasktype
order by t.wave_num
```

As you notice, I don't know anything about the table with the substatuses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join, grouping and count to get your result:
suppose tables are as follow :
cat (1)--->(n) subcat (1)----->(n) subcat_detail.
so the query would be :

```
select cat.title cat_title ,subcat.title subcat_title ,count(*) as cnt from
cat  inner join sub_cat  on cat.id=subcat.cat_id
inner join subcat_detail  on subcat.ID=am.subcat_detail_id
group by cat.title,subcat.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you need different counts, you need to use the CASE statment.

```
select count(*) as total
   , case when field1 = "test' then 1 else 0 end as testcount
   , case when field2 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 endas field2count
FROM table1
```